# Как лучше использовать поля класса? C++

Tags: c++

Есть константа myConst, которую нужно вывести.
Каким способом лучше всего её использовать:

```
class MyClass {
public: 
    const int myConst = 10;
};

int main() {
    MyClass* myclass = new MyClass();
    std::cout << myclass->myConst << std::endl;
    delete myclass;
    return 0;
}
```

**или**

```
class MyClass {
public: 
    static const int myConst = 10;
};

int main() {

    std::cout << MyClass::myConst << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Какая между ними разница?
Пока могу заметить, что во **втором случае** myConst будет существовать всё время существования программы из-за ключевого слова.
А в **первом случае** из-за использования кучи, операции производимые с myclass будут медленнее

Comment: _"операции производимые с myclass будут медленнее"_ - сто тысяч миллионов операций будут медленнее на 7.8наносекунд ..

Comment: Вопрос оторван от реальности. Есть константа, ее надо вывести: `cout << 10 << endl;`

Comment: При нормальной оптимизации это без разницы... https://godbolt.org/z/3aT4Ycbvh

Comment: В первом случае это не константа, а просто поле класса, котому в конструкторе можно придавать произвольное значение. А во втором случае это действительно константа и ее можно использовать например для задания размера массива и т.п.

Comment: @user7860670 "просто поле класса, котому в конструкторе можно придавать произвольное значение" - Как вы измените значение с ключевым словом "const" в первом случае?

Comment: @ArslanI. Я нигде не писал, что буду его где-то изменять. Я написал, что можно задать произвольное значение вместо 10 в конструкторе. `MyClass* myclass = new MyClass{33};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом примере **myConst** является нестатической константой члена класса. Это означает, что каждый объект **MyClass** будет иметь свою копию **myConst**. И даже с учётом того, что значение константы одинаково для всех экземпляров, оно занимает отдельное место в памяти для каждого экземпляра.

В вашем втором примере **myConst** объявлена как **static const int**. Получается, что **myConst** существует в единственном экземпляре независимо от количества объектов **MyClass** и является частью класса, а не отдельных объектов. Доступ к ней осуществляется через имя класса, а не через объекты, что удобно для констант, значение которых общее для всех экземпляров класса. Это также уменьшает потребление памяти, так как не требует выделения отдельной памяти под каждый экземпляр класса.

*Получается что ответ на ваш вопрос:*

Во втором примере, управление памятью оптимизировано лучше и выше производительность.